# Is there a Ruby equivalent of Python's dateutil parser that can parse datetimes from multiple formats?

Tags: python, ruby, datetime, python-dateutil

The dateutil library from Python is super useful for parsing strings of various common formats into datetime objects.  Is there something similar for Ruby?

Comment: What formats do you need to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) and [`Date#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) are in the ruby standard library.  You need to `require 'date'` first.

I have also used the [chronic gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/chronic) when those were insufficient.

Comment: A static code analyzer like rubocop will tell you not to use DateTime and favor Date or Time if one of the simpler classes will do.  Unless a DateTime method is being called with a start argument such as Date::ENGLAND, Date::GREGORIAN, Date::ITALY or Date::JULIAN, it will be less performant.  TLDR: You can almost always use Time instead of DateTime.